# How does one concatenate database values into a string?

Tags: sql, mysql, string

I would like to string together database values into a string.  Something like $a "text" $b.
And then use the entire string as a variable, let's say $c.

Is it better to do this at the database level?  Will php use lots of resources to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perfectly acceptable - calculated or derived field in mysql for example

```
 select
  c.firstname,
  c.lastname,
  concat(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) as fullname
 from
  customer c
 where
  c.cust_id = 1;
```

Comment: The php concat fn works nicely for me.  Thanks for seeding the idea.

      <?php
      $str1 = 'This ';
      $str2 = 'is a ';
      $str3 = 'test string';
      $full = $str1.$str2.$str3;
      echo $full;
      ?>

Comment: +1 A nice language-independent answer :) The solution would work on any MySQL setup, regardless if PHP, Perl, Python, Java etc is used as the language for the application.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the database, in mysql you can use the function
[CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

For example, `UPDATE users SET NAME=CONCAT('asd', 'asdfac') WHERE id=2;`

Answer (score -1):

No, either database or php won't notice this operation.
Better to do in php as it would be a lot readable.